# In C++, when no constructor is declared for a class, what will happen if I construct an object with arguments?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I have the struct student and I did not declare a constructor. What will happen if I do the following?

```
struct student{
    int assns, mt, finalExam;
    float grade(){…}

}
student billy (60, 70, 80);
```

Comment: please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you try it? What does the compiler say?

Comment: Also, what is your goal?  Is it to initialize the 3 `int` members in the order they're declared?  If so, then use the brace initializer instead of the constructor.

Comment: The code will not compile - that's what will happen.

Comment: How do you expect the compiler to know which arguments have been passed for which struct member?

Comment: @Rishi: Well, `strict student billy = {60, 70, 80};` is valid C statement

Answer (score 0):

This answer is written according to the question heading, and not the body, as they seem to be gravely conflicting, hope the OP edits this.

You will encounter a error during compile time.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
class test
{
   int tt;
};

int main ()
{ 
   test t1 (34);
}
```

**Compiler Error:**

```
 In function 'int main()': 
  10:17: error: no matching function for call to 'test::test(int)'       10:17: note: candidates are: 
 2:7: note: test::test() 
 2:7: note: candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided 
 2:7: note: constexpr test::test(const test&)
 2:7: note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'const test&' 
 2:7: note: constexpr test::test(test&&)  
 2:7: note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'test&&'
```

This happens as there is no constructor defined which takes a parameter. Without the ctor there is no meaning of class, as you can never initialize its data member, and how can you expect something to be constructed if the construction company itself is absent.

The compiler will throw error.

Comment: The question heading and body both clearly talk about "no constructor declared", however your example declares a constructor. So I think this is not what OP is asking about.